# How to draw a google line chart using the below code?

Tags: php, mysql, associative-array, google-visualization

I want to draw a line chart using "Google Charts" tools. I'm fetching the data required for the line chart from the MySql database. The code for it is as below:

```
    <?php
    require_once('../includes/public-application-header.php');
    $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","eywaadmin") or die("Failed to connect with database!!!!");
  mysql_select_db("OCN", $con); 

    $sql  =" SELECT DATE_FORMAT( FROM_UNIXTIME( transaction_date ) , '%d/%m/%Y') 'transaction_date', COUNT(*) 'total count', SUM(transaction_status = 'success') ";
    $sql .=" success, SUM(transaction_status = 'inprocess') inprocess, SUM(transaction_status = 'fail') fail, ";
    $sql .=" SUM(transaction_status = 'cancelled') cancelled FROM user_transaction WHERE ";
    $sql .=" transaction_date >= 1325376000 AND transaction_date <= 1373846400 GROUP BY date(FROM_UNIXTIME(transaction_date)) ";

    $r= mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); 
    $transactions = array();
    while($result  = mysql_fetch_array($r, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
      $transactions[] = $result;
    } 
    $rows = array();
      //flag is not needed
      $flag = true;
      $table = array();
      $table['cols'] = array(

    // Labels for your chart, these represent the column titles
    // Note that one column is in "string" format and another one is in "number" format as pie chart only required "numbers" for calculating percentage and string will be used for column title
    array('label' => 'Transaction Date', 'type' => 'string'),
    array('label' => 'Total Count', 'type' => 'number'),
    array('label' => 'Success', 'type' => 'number'),
    array('label' => 'Inprocess', 'type' => 'number'),
    array('label' => 'Failed', 'type' => 'number'),
    array('label' => 'Cancelled', 'type' => 'number'),
    );
  $rows = array();

  foreach($transactions as $tr) {
    $temp = array();

     foreach($tr as $key=>$value){

    // the following line will be used to slice the Pie chart
    $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $key); 

    // Values of each slice
    $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $value);     
    }
  $rows[] = array('c' => $temp); 
}
    $table['rows'] = $rows;

    $jsonTable = json_encode($table);
    //echo $jsonTable;
?>

<html>
    <head>
    <!--Load the Ajax API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
    google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});

    // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {

      // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?=$jsonTable?>);
          var options = {
          title: 'User Transaction Statistics',
          is3D: 'true',
          width: 800,
          height: 600
        };
      // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
      // Do not forget to check your div ID
      var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!--this is the div that will hold the pie chart-->
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to put the dates(i.e. transaction_date) on X-axis and Count values(i.e.10,20,30,40) from on Y-axis. But unfortunately I'm not getting the line chart in the desired format. I'm attaching the screen shot of what I got after executing the above code.

Can anyone please help me in this regard? Thanks in advance. If you want any further information I can add it to the question body.
As per the request from `jmac` I'm posting the json response created for your reference. If you still need ny other thing like the query output, etc. I can provide you. The screenshot of the line -chart is attached.
[image]

Comment: It would help if you gave us a dump of the `data` object you are drawing so that we can see what is actually being plotted as none of us have access to your database and that is where the issue is coming from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that you are saving the column names as well as the column values in the data set. You should just be storing the values.

```
$temp = array();
foreach($tr as $key=>$value){
  // Values of each slice
  $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $value);     
}
$rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
```

The second problem is that you are converting all the values to ints. If you want the date to display as an actual date, you should get rid of that conversion.

```
$temp = array();
foreach($tr as $key=>$value){
  // Values of each slice
  $temp[] = array('v' => $value);     
}
$rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how your jsonTable looks like, but it should be formatted in this way:

```
['transaction date', 'Total count', 'Succes', 'In progress', 'Failed', 'Canceled'],
['19-7-2013', 50, 40, 5, 2, 3],
['20-7-2013', 60, 50, 5, 1, 4],
['21-7-2013', 50, 40, 5, 2, 3],
['22-7-2013', 60, 50, 5, 1, 4],
['23-7-2013', 50, 40, 5, 2, 3]
```

Are you able to send me your $jsonTable?

This link shows you an example of the table: http://jsfiddle.net/kxd2u/

I don't think you have a issue with the amount of data. I made some charts myself with a lot of data and all working fine!

Answer (score 0):

You are inputting your data incorrectly.  Try this:

```
foreach ($transactions as $tr) {
    $temp = array();

    $temp[] = array('v' => $tr['transaction_date']);
    $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $tr['total count']);
    $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $tr['success']);
    $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $tr['inprocess']);
    $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $tr['fail']);
    $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $tr['cancelled']);

    $rows[] = array('c' => $temp); 
}
```

This will produce a chart with a discrete axis, where each row of data is evenly spaced on the chart, regardless of the distance between dates.  If you want a continuous axis (see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/Xfx3h/) as an example of the difference between discrete and continuous), you have to format your dates a bit differently:

in the columns:

```
array('label' => 'Transaction Date', 'type' => 'date')
```

in the rows:

```
$dateArray = explode('/', $tr['transaction_date']);
$year = $dateArray[2];
$month = $dateArray[1] - 1; // need to subtract 1 to convert to javascript month format
$day = $dateArray[0];
$temp[] = array('v' => "Date($year, $month, $day)", f: $tr['transaction_date']);
```

You can then format the date axis in the chart's options:

```
hAxis: {
    format: 'd/M/yyyy'
}
```

As an aside, you can get rid of that $flag variable in PHP - it is an artifact left over from the original code that I posted as an example a long time ago in the Google Visualization API group.  It keeps cropping up whenever that code gets copied, and no one ever deletes it.